# CSS, Javascript, XSL, Moving a row in a table to the bottom of the table

Tags: javascript, css, xslt, checkbox

I have a stylesheet that I am working on where the html file generated from the stylesheet has a toggle button to change a buttom, in a row, in a table ,from a tick to a cross. All buttons come in by default as checked (ticked) ... when the buttom is clicked the tick changes to a cross. What I would like to happen but cannot do is to move the ENTIRE row to the bottom of the table when clicked. The end result is as a row is clicked  the toggle changes to a cross and moves to the base of the table.

Thanks for any help

Tick/cross code

```
/* Customize the label (the container) */
.customcheck {
  position: relative;
}

.customcheck input {
  display: none;
}

.customcheck input~.checkmark {
  background: #ee0b0b;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.customcheck input~.checkmark:after,
.customcheck input~.checkmark:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  left: 12px;
  top: 4px;
}

.customcheck input~.checkmark:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.customcheck input~.checkmark:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.customcheck input:checked~.checkmark {
  background: #3d8a00;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customcheck input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: none;
}

.customcheck input:checked~.checkmark:before {
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 6px;
  top: 2px;
  left: 9px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  height: 13px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

....Stylesheet entry....

```
<tr class="clickable">
          
<td>
<label class="customcheck">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
</td>
```

Comment: Where is the code to move the table row?

Comment: Hi, that is what I need a hand with, another option would be to make the column sortable, how could i make the checkbox column in tne table sortable?

Answer (score 0):

Use `appendChild` to move the `tr` that is clicked `label` to the bottom of its `tbody` container:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('tr.clickable').forEach(
  l => l.addEventListener(
         'click', 
         e => e.currentTarget.parentNode.appendChild(e.currentTarget)
       )
);
```

```css
/* Customize the label (the container) */
.customcheck {
  position: relative;
}

.customcheck input {
  display: none;
}

.customcheck input~.checkmark {
  background: #ee0b0b;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.customcheck input~.checkmark:after,
.customcheck input~.checkmark:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  left: 12px;
  top: 4px;
}

.customcheck input~.checkmark:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.customcheck input~.checkmark:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.customcheck input:checked~.checkmark {
  background: #3d8a00;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customcheck input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: none;
}

.customcheck input:checked~.checkmark:before {
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 6px;
  top: 2px;
  left: 9px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  height: 13px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>data</th>
      <th>action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable">
       <td>row 1</td>
       <td><label class="customcheck"><input type="checkbox" checked><span class="checkmark"></span></label></td>
    </tr><tr class="clickable">
       <td>row 2</td>
       <td><label class="customcheck"><input type="checkbox" checked><span class="checkmark"></span></label></td>
    </tr><tr class="clickable">
       <td>row 3</td>
       <td><label class="customcheck"><input type="checkbox" checked><span class="checkmark"></span></label></td>
    </tr><tr class="clickable">
       <td>row 4</td>
       <td><label class="customcheck"><input type="checkbox" checked><span class="checkmark"></span></label></td>
    </tr><tr class="clickable">
       <td>row 5</td>
       <td><label class="customcheck"><input type="checkbox" checked><span class="checkmark"></span></label></td>
    </tr><tr class="clickable">
       <td>row 6</td>
       <td><label class="customcheck"><input type="checkbox" checked><span class="checkmark"></span></label></td>
    </tr><tr class="clickable">
       <td>row 7</td>
       <td><label class="customcheck"><input type="checkbox" checked><span class="checkmark"></span></label></td>
    </tr><tr class="clickable">
       <td>row 8</td>
       <td><label class="customcheck"><input type="checkbox" checked><span class="checkmark"></span></label></td>
    </tr><tr class="clickable">
       <td>row 9</td>
       <td><label class="customcheck"><input type="checkbox" checked><span class="checkmark"></span></label></td>
    </tr><tr class="clickable">
       <td>row 10</td>
       <td><label class="customcheck"><input type="checkbox" checked><span class="checkmark"></span></label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you your code  works the exactly the way I would LIKE my code to work, I still have an issue with my code though (not moving down).... but it certainly helps me look for my issue